# Persist Database in Android after upgrade

Tags: android

I have an android application with some tables in my sqlite DB and i want to upgrade my application and thus i need to change some of my existing tables structure and also need to add new tables which can contain data from older tables. How can i manage this with out loosing the data saved by users?

Comment: first copy your database from device to any other place like sdcard. after that update your database. insert copied database values in to new database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the fields that you need. In [onUpgrade()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) first create your new tables then copy the required fields to new table. Then remove the columns and rows that you don"t want in the older tables and also drop it if you don"t want it more

See [this](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-database-tutorial.html) usefull tutorial too..

Answer (score 2):

That's what `onUpgrade()` method is called for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

If DB version differs, you can deal with structure update in that method.